# gem install bson_ext issues

Tags: ruby, rbenv, bson-ext

I am running genghisapp - the gem for Mongo management. When I run it it gives me a warning that the native BSON extension was not loaded and suggest I run `gem install bson_ext`.

I have recently installed `rbenv` and have my gems such as `genghisapp` installed in `~/.gem` which is on my path and loads fine.

My first attempt was to run `gem install bson_ext` but after restarting mongo/shell had no effect - the message is still there.

I then suspected this was not a genghisapp message but a Mongo one so thought I might need to install this as sudo. However this resulted in breaking my rbenv install due to permissions being now set to root/whatever because I was still using the local rbenv gem.

What is the proper way to solve this? Should I find the OSX gem and call its full path to install or do I need to specify something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because a) the version of mongo and bson_ext must match and b) there must not be any other bson_ext version installed.

The comments on this [issue](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/issues/187) helped me solved the issue.

Run: `gem list | grep -w 'bson\|bson_ext\|mongo'` which will print out all the versions. It should look like:

```
bson (1.9.2)
bson_ext (1.9.2)
mongo (1.9.2)
```

And not like:

```
bson (2.3.0, 1.10.2, 1.9.2)
bson_ext (1.10.2, 1.9.2)
mongo (1.10.2, 1.9.2)
```

If so, (de)install versions as necessary.